# How do I interpret this summation-integral notation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, notation, integration

Reading a paper I came across this abomination of a notation, my question is, how do I interpret it?

For context I'll post the whole page + the notation as a separate.

[image]

The notation in mind is this weird summation-integral from P to B [image]

How am I supposed to read that?

Comment: @user190081 That should be an answer

Comment: May I ask what equation B1 is as it seems to be the definition of the integral, just curious as why that wasn't mention in the original post

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the case, but according to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68351/what-is-the-command-for-a-sum-symbol-superimposed-on-an-integral-sign), it is a **sum over all discrete states and an integral over all continuum states.**